# Computing future date based on stored timestamps value

Tags: postgresql

Trying to build a nested query which returns expiry date, basically calculated using purchase_date and using dynamic interval entry from the same table (integer that indicate days)

```
SELECT  (
        SELECT
            (
                (
                    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP- CAST (
                        cc.field2 || ' days' AS INTERVAL
                    )
                )-dp.date_purchased
            )
        FROM
            cc
        WHERE
            cc.field1 = 'days_since_order'
    ) AS expiry_date,
    dp.*
FROM purchase dp
```

Above query would return expiry date as `14 days 10:21:36` while I would like to simply return the date the item expires on based on purchase_date, timestamp and interval by days

Comment: Oi, perhaps `dp.date_purchased+(...)`?

Comment: How do tables `purchase` and `cc` relate to each other?

Comment: Patrick, there is additional relation in the where clause.. I just removed extra code to keep only part am facing problems with, should I add it back? Would it help?

Comment: Abstractpaper; doesn't work

Comment: @MoJ.Mughrabi check [this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html) out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The

```
date_part('year', valid_date)
```

function may help you.

I've tested this on a date and it seems to do what you need.

Ref [Postgresql 9.5 data_part function: EXTRACT(field FROM source)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT)

Hope this helps